# inMemoryAuthentication did not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using `spring Security 4.0.4`.

But when I post my username and password to '\login'. it always be Denied.

I use java-base config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");//dba have two roles.
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("nickname").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

    }
}
```

and my login.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="loginCtrl" action="/login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group input-login">
        <label  class="control-label sr-only">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="nickname" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" name="nickname" placeholder="NickName">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-login">
        <label  class="control-label sr-only">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group sub-login">
        <div class=" col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried post the nickname 'admin' and password 'root123' .But always be denied.I do not know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csrf protection may be the cause of it. Can you try disabling it (just to be sure the problem is related to that matter) :

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("nickname").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
```

If the problem is indeed the csrf then you should read this spring documentation which explains how to send the token.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html